# How can I disable session state in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-state, tempdata

I would like to have a very lightweight ASP.NET MVC site which includes removing as many of the usual HttpModules as possible and disabling session state. However when I try to do this, I get the following error:

`The SessionStateTempDataProvider requires SessionState to be enabled.`

I've disabled session state in web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

I understand that ASP.NET MVC uses session state for TempData, but I don't need/want TempData - I just want to disable session state. Help!

Comment: Nice idea - I'd be interested to hear if you encountered any other issues with this and how lightweight you were able to get in the end.

Comment: I didn't do much more experimenting after I implemented Steve's changes, but there was still a fair amount of overhead. The fastest I've been able to get ASP.NET going has been with straight IHttpHandler implementations. See my answer here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509978/something-faster-than-httphandlers/510001#510001

Comment: This is fixed in MVC 2. We fixed the session state temp data provider that it won't throw unless you actually try to read/write the temp data.

Comment: Brad: Excellent, good to know!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could make your own ControllerFactory and DummyTempDataProvider. Something like this:

```
public class NoSessionControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
  protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
  {
    var controller = base.GetControllerInstance(controllerType);
    ((Controller) controller).TempDataProvider = new DummyTempDataProvider();
    return controller;
  }
}


public class DummyTempDataProvider : ITempDataProvider
{
  public IDictionary<string, object> LoadTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext)
  {
    return new Dictionary<string, object>();
  }

  public void SaveTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary<string, object> values)
  {
  }
}
```

And then you would just need to register the controller factory on app startup - e.g. you could do this in global.asax:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NoSessionControllerFactory());
```

Comment: Thanks... still not ideal (to me at least), but still better than doing it on each controller.

Comment: Sorry, that sounded really ungrateful... didn't mean it to be :D

Comment: hehe, no problem :) I understand it could seem like more code than you'd ideally want for what seems like it should be a configurable thing, but one of the big strengths of ASP.NET MVC is this type of configuration through providing alternative implementations via code. It gives you a lot of power to get in there and do things the way you want and overall I'd say it's really a 'good thing'. Personally I prefer typing C# code than xml anyway ;)

Comment: Hi Steve. I just implemented your code in my proj. It works well. Thanks! Now I have Session disabled.

Comment: I added one more piece to my solution in the SaveTempData method:

if ( values.Count != 0 ) throw new NotImplementedException("Can not set tempdata, no session state available");

http://tinyurl.com/mbegfr

Comment: Good idea Bill, that would avoid some hard-to-debug missing state issues I'm sure :)

Comment: This was improved with MVC3, just add `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]` to your controller.

Comment: Or use <sessionState mode="Off" /> to disable it globally. This is an ancient bug fixed doggie decades ago.

Comment: @RickAndMSFT You're saying to do exactly what the OP says he did.  But in doing so he's getting the SessionStateTempDataProvider  required error.

Answer (score 9):

I've found one way, which I don't particularly care for:

**Create NoTempDataProvider**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Facebook.Sites.Desktop.Auth.Models
{
    public class NoTempDataProvider : ITempDataProvider
    {
        #region [ ITempDataProvider Members ]

        public IDictionary<String, Object> LoadTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            return new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        }

        public void SaveTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary<String, Object> values) { }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Manually Overwrite the Provider in the Controller**

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    public AuthController()
    {
        this.TempDataProvider = new NoTempDataProvider();
    }
}
```

I would greatly prefer a way to do this completely via the configuration, but this works for now.

Comment: Yes, your way is similar to the way I outlined in my answer - although you don't have to manually override the TempDataProvider in each controller if you provide a custom ControllerFactory to handle it for you.

Comment: You can also create a base Controller class, and configure the TempDataProvider in it's constructor.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to use TempData for simple strings, you can use the CookieTempDataProvider in MvcFutures http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471.

Answer (score 1):

According to Brad Wilson, this has been fixed in MVC 2 Preview 1. See [here](http://crinket.com/session-state-for-aspnet-mvc) and [here](http://twitter.com/bradwilson/status/3614026482).

Answer (score 0):

Modern solution:

> In ASP.NET, if you do not use the Session object to store any data or
>   if any of the Session events (Session_OnStart or Session_OnEnd) is
>   handled, session state is disabled.

So not using Session (or TempData), disables Session State.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/306996/how-to-disable-asp-session-state-in-asp-net)