# How to enable session only in specific view and disable it on others in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, session

i need to use session only on a few views in my MVC project. These views are not visible to web crawlers.
I use cookieless="AutoDetect" so web-crawles(and users with cookies disabled) gets ugly url from IIS( ie "(S(hkec1uq1onbt0xafixedjc45))/en/home.mvc") even on pages that doesn't need session.

Is there any way how to enable session only on specific pages and disable on others?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling session is not exactly prefered "out of the box" for ASP.NET MVC.  I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884852/how-can-i-disable-session-state-in-asp-net-mvc) will get you going down the right path.