# SaveTempData called even though session is disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, tempdata

I've disabled sessionState in my mvc2 app via the web.config and also created my own controllerfactory and dummy tempdata provider, as described here:

[How can I disable session state in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884852/how-can-i-disable-session-state-in-asp-net-mvc/884904#884904)

Only I've made it so that SaveTempData throws an exception:

```
 public void SaveTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                          IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(
        "Cannot set tempdata, no session state is available.");
    }
```

I've made sure that no code is ever using either the Session or the TempData objects, but I still see this exception getting thrown after the "OnResultExecuted" event has been raised. I used to use this very same pattern on my mvc1 site and never saw the exception. Any ideas?

If I change my "SaveTempData" implementation to this:

```
public void SaveTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                         IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        if (values.Count != 0)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(
            "Cannot set tempdata, no session state is available.");
        }
    }
```

Everything works as expected - I'm just hoping to learn why SaveTempData is called at all when I'm not using it anywhere.

**Update**

Discovered this article: http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/

Which explains that ExecuteCore calls PossiblyLoadTempData and PossiblySaveTempData around an action - which is what was causing my issue. Is this a new addition in mvc2 vs. mvc1?

Comment: Note: I get this error with either AppFabric or standard InProc session state. Originally thought it was AppFabric causing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it is implemented in the `Controller.ExecuteCore` method. The `LoadTempData` and `SaveTempData` methods will always be called before and after each action so make sure that they do not throw an exception. In order to disable the session effectively I would recommend you putting the following in your web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

Comment: Just discovered this article:
http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/
Which shows that it's called in ExecuteCore, which I didn't realize. Was this a change in mvc2 vs. mvc1? Just for everyone's reference, I *do* have "<sessionState mode="Off" />" set set in my web.config

Answer (score 1):

Discovered this article: http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/

Which explains that ExecuteCore calls PossiblyLoadTempData and PossiblySaveTempData around an action - which is what was causing my issue. Is this a new addition in mvc2 vs. mvc1?