# ASP Server reduce session timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout

I'm running a website on a shared ASP.NET 4.0 server.Therefore I only have limited memory size to store my users' session state.

The program I've written doesn't use Session variables: once a page is ready it is sent to the user and voilà. The rest is JavaScript and when the user click a link, I don't care if a new session is to be opened.

The question is: what if I reduce the session timeout to say 1 muinute only?
Will the user suffer from extra delays?

What if I go sessionless?

Since I do not use login-password for the users, I'm suspecting it won't impact the performances. Am I right?
Is there any cave at?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are only needed if you need to store some "state" - to "remember" or "know" something about a **specific** client (user/browser) on the server-side (you can use cookies on the client side).

If you have no need to do so, you can [turn off sesssions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306996)..

For [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884852/how-can-i-disable-session-state-in-asp-net-mvc) (note the comment by Brad Wilson for MVC2)