# Cannot access Session value declared in one controller in another controller in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

So in my MVC App I require the user to login, handled by the AccountController,

And after successful login I save some extra properties to the session like so

```
Member member = dbContextRead.Members.Include(m => m.Location).SingleOrDefault(e => e.AspNetUserId == user.Id);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["member"] = member;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["location"] = member.Location;
```

But when I try to access the session in another controller and fetch the values it returns null.

```
var member = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["member"] as Member) ?? dbContext.Members.Single(m => m.AspNetUserId == user.Id);
```

Also a good thing to add, if I check the Session Id in the 2 different locations, they return a different session id and a different instance.

Why is that? Am I missing something, should this be setup somewhere?

Comment: @mjwills yes, I put a breakpoint on 2 different locations and the declaration of the session value executes first.

Comment: What is the value of `member.GetType()` when the setting occurs?

Comment: @mjwills There are only 2 places - where I used them. Login and the Access controller.

Comment: Is Session State disabled? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884852/how-can-i-disable-session-state-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Is `Member` class serializable?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya hmm, no. Is it necessary?

Comment: @mjwills Yeah, i've tried storing an integer and can't access it as well. It might have something to do with those 2 controllers having a different instance of Session

Comment: Are they both in the same browser? Logged in as the same user? Is Session State disabled?

Comment: If you need to store class objects into session they need to be serializable.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, same browser, logged in as the same user, and no session state is not disabled

Comment: @mjwills <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="480" />

Comment: are those MVC controllers or WebAPI controllers?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu MVC