# Improve the overall performance of a HttpRequest in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, performance

I'm building a very slimmed down website. And I would like to know what I can do, to improve performance as much as possible.

The site should do something like,

1. fetch a header from the request.
2. make an asynchronous SOAP call.
3. redirect the request to another server.

To be able to do this I also need to be able to use the cache. So! What can I do to improve the performance of this small service? What HttpModules can I unload? Should I use a webform page? Should I write a HttpHandler? Are there any other tips?

I know this is might be pseudo optimizing, but this service will be under very heavy load for short times and I would like to know that I did as much as I could.

Comment: What are you wanting to optimize? Processor, Request Size?

Comment: I would like to optimize the request processing. The Request size will be very small since it will just register stuff server side and then redirect the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working with HttpHandlers in an attempt to create a *very* fast tiny website. See the accepted answer for this question I asked here on SO: [Something faster than HttpHandlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509978/something-faster-than-httphandlers).

Generally I would say an HttpHandler and turning off the HttpModules you don't need, should be a very effective solution. You're heading in the right direction with your own suggestions.

Comment: That's a great answer to your question that you linked.  +1's all around over there.

Comment: Ah nice question. To bad I didn't find it before I asked =)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use an HttpHandler instead of a Page.  This will remove all the lifecycle processing that Page objects go through.

Ultimately, if you need to "extreme optimize", you could code an ISAPI filter.  This would be a last resort though.

Comment: The ISAPI filter suggestion is great. But I need a small selfwritten .net dll as well so its a no go.