# What is the Fastest .net web solution?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax, ajax.net

Most of my experience has been with designing layouts, JavaScript and Silverlight but I am looking to create a very fast .net web solution.

I am curious what the fastest .net solution would be to create a site that has pages that need to refresh data on them ever 1 to 2 seconds and I also would like to avoid view states so the pages will have a nice clean look.

All the data will be coming from caches on the server not directly from the database.

I figured I will be using services of some kind but not sure what type of project to start this as.

Comment: "I also would like to avoid view states so the pages will have a nice clean look" - How does ViewState affect the way the page looks?

Comment: Wait... What? How does the view state effect how the page looks?

Comment: He meant HTML behind the page.

Comment: Look at asp.net MVC3 with jquery or something similar, fast is relative to what your setup is, the amount of data you are pushing and what type of forms you are using... You will have to do an investigation yourself and understand the different asp.net technologies beforehand though

Comment: If I use MVC3 with jQuery will I still need to use WebServices to get fast refresh of data?

Comment: @Widor @mdm Realy are you just looking for a excuse to mark people down.

Comment: @JCPhlux: For the record, I haven't "marked you down" at all. Clear, concise communication is as important in Tech fields as it is in life. Getting your message across without ambiguity will get you better answers on here, as people spend less time deciphering what you mean and more time formulating an answer that fits your exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good thinking will be to avoid ASP.NET controls as much as possible, disable ViewState and ViewStateMac meaning you will be needed to work with jQuery which will load Data from your Caches via WCF WebServices. This will give you clean HTML, fast performance and maintainability.

**Important note::** in fact will look cleaner but will be much harder to implement rather using native controls and native Ajax.

Comment: If I use WCF Web services do I even need to bother with a asp.net project at that point could I just write HTML and have the same results.

Comment: Yep, you can use simple HTML but in application i do with more or less same specifications i must have Sessions and some basic logic hence i must use simplified ASP.NET without all the mess with ViewState and security/functional modules except Session.

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing an HttpHandler to render your output. It doesn't get much faster than that.

I asked a similar question in the past, [Something faster than HttpHandlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509978/something-faster-than-httphandlers), and [Daniel Schaffers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509978/something-faster-than-httphandlers/510001#510001) is a great checklist for high performance websites in .NET.

Comment: ASP.NET page is more sophisticated implementation of HttpHandler this is why Handler would perform faster, maybe even than Web Service. With HttpHandler your development proccess is different than with Web Service because you don't even need objects but partial HTML ( HTML with only stuff you want to show). So you can render partial HTML which you can load via $.Ajax or even simpler methods like $.load but again it depends on application on application requirements and ideas you have to implement those.